# using jQuery on only one page

Tags: functions, jquery

In my functions.php file I am loading a particular js script on only the page it is required, as I don't want to load it unnecessarily on pages that don't require it.

```
function tabs_enqueue() {
    if(is_page( 205 )) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ui/jquery-ui.min.js', [], '1.8', true);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabs_enqueue');
```

After testing, this works 100% but my problem is that I don't know where to put the actual jquery on the page that I want it. I can't put it into the footer because then I get errors on the other pages because it is trying to run the code without the js file being loaded. I want to place the code just before the closing body tag. If I put this after the get_footer() code then it is right at the bottom of the source code and if I put it before the get_footer() then it is called before I even load the js files. So, how would I get this code to display just before the closing body tag?

```
 <script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        //code here

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You also probably don't need to use your themes jquery UI when [WordPress has it in core](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it on a template, you can use the [wp_add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) function. It'd be something like:

```
function tabs_enqueue() {
    if(is_page( 205 )) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ui/jquery-ui.min.js', [], '1.8', true);
        wp_add_inline_script( 'ui',
            'jQuery(window).load(function() {
                //code here
            });' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabs_enqueue');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

While Felipe Elia's answer works, it's better to separate your code. You don't want to have to update your PHP file to change Javascript.

I would add a reference to your javascript file within your page check and be sure to include 'ui' in your required array so your new script won't load until after 'ui' is loaded.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myScript.js', ['ui']);
```

Then create a file (js/myScript.js) that holds your custom Javascript. I recommend putting your code in a closure so it doesn't get affected by any other scripts.

```
(function($, window, document){
    // Use strict mode to reduce development errors.
    "use strict";

    // Put your code here.

})(jQuery, window, document);
```